# how can i append form data to a csv file in asp and email users at the same time?

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp-classic

I have a referral form that a user can refer friends for membership. The form action has to point to an asp file. (I started in php and got it working on a different server, but the server it needs to be on must be asp). I have searched and searched and I am having some issues. (I am an asp newbie)

1. The form must send an email to the users. I got this working in an asp file here(**email.asp**):

   ```
   <%
   Dim senderName, senderEmail, senderMessage
   Dim name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8, name9, name10
   Dim email1, email2, email3, email4, email5, email6, email7, email8, email9, email10
   senderName = Request.Form("senderName")
   senderEmail = Request.Form("senderEmail")
   senderMessage = Request.Form("senderMessage")
   name1 = Request.Form("name1")
   name2 = Request.Form("name2")
   name3 = Request.Form("name3")
   name4 = Request.Form("name4")
   name5 = Request.Form("name5")
   name6 = Request.Form("name6")
   name7 = Request.Form("name7")
   name8 = Request.Form("name8")
   name9 = Request.Form("name9")
   name10 = Request.Form("name10")
   email1 = Request.Form("email1")
   email2 = Request.Form("email2")
   email3 = Request.Form("email3")
   email4 = Request.Form("email4")
   email5 = Request.Form("email5")
   email6 = Request.Form("email6")
   email7 = Request.Form("email7")
   email8 = Request.Form("email8")
   email9 = Request.Form("email9")
   email10 = Request.Form("email10")   

   'Sends an email
   Dim mail
   Set mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
   'for testing i am only sending to the first email
   mail.To = email1
   mail.From = senderEmail
   mail.Subject = "Join Dallas Cowboys True Blue Fan Club with me!"
   mail.TextBody = "Join Dallas Cowboys True Blue Fan Club with me!"
   mail.Send()
   Response.Write("Mail Sent!")
   'Destroy the mail object!
   Set mail = nothing
   %>
   ```
2. Finally, I have a working aspx file (**append.aspx**) that will append the form data to a csv file. The real issue i have is combining both files into just 1 working file.

   ```
   <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = window.close();
   </script>
   <script language="vb" runat="server">
   sub Page_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
   'Open a file for writing
   Dim FILENAME as String = Server.MapPath("Output.csv")

   Dim senderName, senderEmail, senderMessage
   Dim name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8, name9, name10
   Dim email1, email2, email3, email4, email5, email6, email7, email8, email9, email10
   senderName = Request.Form("senderName")
   senderEmail = Request.Form("senderEmail")
   senderMessage = Request.Form("senderMessage")
   name1 = Request.Form("name1")
   name2 = Request.Form("name2")
   name3 = Request.Form("name3")
   name4 = Request.Form("name4")
   name5 = Request.Form("name5")
   name6 = Request.Form("name6")
   name7 = Request.Form("name7")
   name8 = Request.Form("name8")
   name9 = Request.Form("name9")
   name10 = Request.Form("name10")
   email1 = Request.Form("email1")
   email2 = Request.Form("email2")
   email3 = Request.Form("email3")
   email4 = Request.Form("email4")
   email5 = Request.Form("email5")
   email6 = Request.Form("email6")
   email7 = Request.Form("email7")
   email8 = Request.Form("email8")
   email9 = Request.Form("email9")
   email10 = Request.Form("email10")   

   'Get a StreamWriter class that can be used to write to the file
   Dim objStreamWriter as StreamWriter
   objStreamWriter = File.AppEndText(FILENAME)

   'AppEnd the the End of the string, "A user viewed this demo at: "
   'followed by the current date and time
   objStreamWriter.WriteLine(sEnderName & "," & sEnderEmail & "," & name1 & "," & email1 & "," & senderMessage & "," & DateTime.Now.ToString())
   If name2 <> "" then
   objStreamWriter.WriteLine("," & "," & name2 & "," & email2)
   End If
   If name3 <> "" then
   objStreamWriter.WriteLine("," & "," & name3 & "," & email3)
   End If
   If name4 <> "" then
   objStreamWriter.WriteLine("," & "," & name4 & "," & email4)
   End If
   If name5 <> "" then
   objStreamWriter.WriteLine("," & "," & name5 & "," & email5)
   End If
   If name6 <> "" then
   objStreamWriter.WriteLine("," & "," & name6 & "," & email6)
   End If
   If name7 <> "" then
   objStreamWriter.WriteLine("," & "," & name7 & "," & email7)
   End If
   If name8 <> "" then
   objStreamWriter.WriteLine("," & "," & name8 & "," & email8)
   End If
   If name9 <> "" then
   objStreamWriter.WriteLine("," & "," & name9 & "," & email9)
   End If
   If name10 <> "" then
   objStreamWriter.WriteLine("," & "," & name10 & "," & email10)
   End If
   'Close the stream
   objStreamWriter.Close()
   End sub
   </script>
   ```

Comment: For writing to files in classic ASP, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898188/cant-write-file-in-classic-asp

Comment: Thanks for the tip mellamokb, but that doesn't help me accomplish what I need to do as when I use that code and change it to my filename, it still will not work and I get a 500 error from my email.asp page.

Comment: I seem to be getting the same result as the person on that post - no error, and file does not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use System.Net.Mailmessage and SmtpClient.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

Comment: I can get the mail to work perfectly in an asp page and I can get the data to append to a csv file perfectly using an aspx page. I can't, though, seem to combine the code into one single asp or aspx file to handle the form data.

Comment: use this ASP.net  Class to send the email in ASP.net... thats alll

Comment: ahhh i see what you are saying now - i will try and test the result. Thanks again!